# API for Java backend

Tags: java, compiler-construction

Is there an API for the javac backend? Instead of hacking the call to main with command line args and what not like they do it [here](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/javacmain.html).  Ideally I'd like to specify in/out streams for source and generated bytecode - do not want to deal with classloaders and class paths headache.

I couldn't find any javadoc for the  com.sun.tools.javac either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [`javax.tools.JavaCompiler`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) (available since Java 6).